# Migrating smaller SSD to a larger one while preserving recovery partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, recovery-partition

I have bought a Dell XPS 13 with 128 GB SSD drive, soon I've realized that 128 GB is simply not enough, so I bought a bigger 500 GB SSD drive to upgrade my new laptop.

I want to preserve the recovery partitions as I do have a real need to re-image my OS (Windows 8.1) every now and then (plus my OCD won't let me loose it).

I have tried backing up and then restoring with Acronis which was a great success until the part that I wanted to expand the size of drive `C:` with the unallocated space in the drive, but since the drive and the unallocated space were not adjacent, I wasn't able to do it (tried this using Windows's Disk Manager and GParted, both failed to do so).

I don't mind losing the data but I do mind losing the recovery partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lots and lots of solutions and programs that promises the world I found out that the only one that was actually capable of expanding a partition that is not adjacent to the unallocated space is **Acronis Disk Director**, it takes care of everything that needs to be taken care of.

To complete the answer, I have used Acronis True Image in order to create an exact copy of my older SSD drive and restored it into the new SSD drive which caused it to have 450GB of unallocated space. Then I have used Acronis Disk Director to expand the OS partition.